# Initialize an array with another array in member initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, initializer-list

I am writing the constructor for class `A` below. `mutex_array` calls the default `std::mutex` constructor, which is fine. I then want to construct each element of `unique_lock_array` from each element of `std::mutex` in the member initializer list. That is, `unique_lock_array[i]` should be a unique lock for `mutex_array[i]` before the body of the constructor. Is that possible?

```
#include <array>
#include <mutex>

class A {
public:
    A() : unique_lock_array(/* ??? */) {}

private:
    std::array<std::mutex, 10> mutex_array;
    std::array<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, 10> unique_lock_array;
};
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Default-initialize the locks, then in the construction function body use a simple loop to assign the correct locks to the elements.

Comment: It is possible syntactically, but it is semantically incorrect to lock multiple mutices in this way. You should use `std::scoped_lock` instead to avoid deadlocking.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm not sure what you mean. The mutexes were just constructed, so there won't be any deadlocking in the constructor. The mutexes are independently locked and unlocked by member functions of ```A```, so ```scoped_lock``` won't help with anything.

Comment: @user17732522 I think you might think the mutexes are locked during the lifetime of ```A```, which wouldn't be useful. Whatever solution I find here, I'm just adding a ```std::defer_lock``` to it. The mutexes won't even be locked in/after the constructor.

Comment: @Bobby I was assuming you simplified the example for demonstration purposes. In most situations that construction is dangerous. Yes, with the specific code in the example it is fine.

Comment: @JaMiT no. That is constructing an array with a single value. This is constructing each element of an array with an element of a different array. Although it looks like neither will have satisfying answers for similar reasons.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how do you propose assigning the correct locks after construction? The only way I see it is to create a temporary ```unique_lock``` and swap the two.

Comment: @Bobby *"That is constructing an array with a single value. This is constructing each element of an array with an element of a different array"* -- That is a trivial difference. The "single value" to pass to the helper function is `mutex_array`. Changing `def` to `def[Is]` (using the notation in the accepted answer) is fairly tame. *In fact, you can drop some of the complexity of that answer **because** each element is initialized to something different. The expression `(Is, void(), def[Is])...` can be simplified to `def[Is]...`*

Comment: [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) have an [rvalue assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/operator%3D), which means you could do e.g. `unique_lock_array[i] = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex_array[i])`

Comment: *"Is that possible?"* -- A more interesting question is if it can be done succinctly, which is what others have answered. Strictly speaking, for "possible", did you try the brute-force approach? `A() : unique_lock_array({std::unique_lock{mutex_array[0]}, std::unique_lock{mutex_array[1]}, std::unique_lock{mutex_array[2]}}) {}` (keep going with the copy-paste-edit to get all 10 entries initialized)

Answer (score 1):

You need a helper function but that is easy to do now with an immediately executed lambda expression.  That would give you

```
class A {
public:
    A() : unique_lock_array([&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
                            {
                                return std::array{std::unique_lock{mutex_array[Is]}...}; 
                            }(std::make_index_sequence<10>{})) {}

private:
    std::array<std::mutex, 10> mutex_array;
    std::array<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, 10> unique_lock_array;
};
```

Comment: While this works, is it really "better" (or simpler) than a plain loop inside the body? ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No clue.  It makes a lot more assembly code, but I'm not well versed in that so no idea if the unrolled loop is better or not.  I just wanted to show of the array building technique.